# Stopping a WordPress plugin from loading a css file in the header

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the plugin 'Ninja From' and I'm trying to stop it from loading a CSS file in the header.

The code that shows up when the `wp_head()` is called:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='nf-display-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/assets/css/display-structure.css?ver=4.7.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

My code:

```
function remove_css_ninja_form(){
    wp_dequeue_style('nf-display-css');
    wp_deregister_style('nf-display-css');
    wp_dequeue_style('nf-display');
    wp_deregister_style('nf-display');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_css_ninja_form', 99999 );
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'remove_css_ninja_form', 99999 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_css_ninja_form', 9999 );
```

It is not working.

The PHP code from the plugin that's loading the CSS file:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'nf-display', $css_dir . 'display-structure.css', array( 'dashicons' ) );
```

Comment: I have also tried `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'remove_css_ninja_form', 999 );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ninja Forms has a custom action you can use to dequeue the CSS.

```
function wpse_nf_dequeue_styles() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'nf-display' );
}
add_action( 'nf_display_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_nf_dequeue_styles' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_ninjafrom_style() {
    wp_dequeue_style( "nf-display" );
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'remove_ninjafrom_style', 100);
```